# SQL DATE convert/cast with CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, datetime

I was able to resolve the issue with your input. Thanks for all your help and quick responses. This is very helpful community!

I have query that I am trying to fix where I was able to get desired output but  getting blank spaces in destination column when source is NULL . I would like to have NULL when source is NULL.

I am using Invoicedate and converting into Invoicedatetext.

Invoice Date format is YYYY-MM-DD and Invoice date text desired output is YYYYDDMM so without - .

Is there better way to write and also can I have NULL when source is NULL.

Here is my code :

```sql
Select Invoicedate, CASE WHEN invoicedate = '' THEN NULL ELSE 

cast (concat(datepart(yy,invoicedate), RIGHT ('00'+cast (datepart(mm,invoicedate) as varchar (2)),2), RIGHT ('00'+cast (datepart(dd,invoicedate) as varchar (2)),2), AS VARCHAR (10)) END as Invoice_date_text
```

Note: Invoicedate is date format and Invoicedatetext is varchar format.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Invoice Date format is YYYY-MM-DD and Invoice date text desired output is YYYYDDMM so without"*  `date` and the other date and time data types don't have a format, they are binary values. This isn't something for SQL, it's for your presentation layer. You should be tagging what ever language your application is in, and showing your application code if you aren't sure how to change the format that is **presented** to the user.

Comment: If, however, you're storing a Date (and time) value in a `(n)varchar` column then you need to fix that, ASAP. [varchar is NOT a one size fits all data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/). Store the data in a data type appropriate for the data; there are 6 date and time data types and 5 of them are infinately *far* more appropriate for date data than a `(n)varchar`.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. Your question is unclear, please add sample data and expected results, in formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

YYYYDDMM is rather arcane format.  It is not built into SQL Server as a value for `convert()`, but you can readily construct it.

If you can accept a number in the right format, then:

```
select year(invoicedate) * 10000 + day(invoicedate) * 100 + month(invoicedate) as yyyyddmm
```

You can readily convert to a string:

```
select convert(varchar(8),
               year(invoicedate) * 10000 + day(invoicedate) * 100 + month(invoicedate)
              )
```

You can also use `format()`:

```
select format(invoicedate, 'yyyyddMM')
```

As a note:  You can tweak the above methods to support YYYYMMDD as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `CONVERT(varchar(8), Invoicedate, 112)`

In answer to the null issue, this is not a problem with `CONVERT`. If you really need `CONCAT`, be aware that `CONCAT` will ignore nulls, instead switch to `+`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to fetch data from monthofservice column which is character (YYYYMM) format. It has 202012 so would like to select only 3 to 6 character and name it as servicedatetext as 2012 (YYMM ) format so it  needs some adjustment in my code below as it is showing BLANK when monthofservice has NULL.

I would like to have NULL in new column when it is NULL in the monthofservice.  

I am using  CAST(CONCAT(substring(MonthofService,3,2),substring(MonthofService,5,2)) as Varchar (4)) as servicedatetext 
Please help with code ? Thanks!

Comment: `SUBSTRING(MonthofService, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean your target is YYYYMMDD. Try this one :

```
    --drop table #datetest
    create table #datetest (Invoicedate  date)
    insert into #datetest (Invoicedate)
    VALUES ('2020-12-31'), 
        (NULL)
    
    SELECT  Invoicedate  , 
            CASE WHEN Invoicedate  IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),Invoicedate,112)
              ELSE NULL
              END
    FROM #datetest
```

You can find the list of different datetime target formats [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `CASE` can be replaced by `ISNULL` buy you don't need it because `CONVERT` will return null anyway

Comment: Thanks for datetime target format list! I am using source to select and then loading data using SSIS package. CONVERT(varchar(8),Invoicedate,112) worked fine.